# Getting a GeoServer talking to an AWS RDS?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, postgis, geoserver

I have an issue that's killing me. I have an AWS account and am hosting a GeoServer instance up there within a Docker container, launched through a docker-compose file. It works perfectly fine. I also have a PostgreSQL RDS instance up there. As far as I can tell, it's working fine. Getting them to communicate, that's been my problem.

My issue is that everything I've found indicates that GeoServer utilizes only PostSQL natively, and PostgreSQL not at all. AWS doesn't give the option to create a PostSQL RDS but, as it's an extension of PostgreSQL, this avenue seems the simplest to pursue.

So my challenge is to find a way for my dockerized GeoServer application to communicate with the RDS, and I'm leaning in the direction of incorporating the PostSQL extension into my docker-compose file. But this is all well over my head, as I've only begun learning these things recently, and it's specific enough that Google has hardly been a help at all. Can anyone give me some guidance with this endeavor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to add PostGIS (the spatial extension to PostgreSQL) to an RDS instance, see the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.PostGIS) for a detailed guide. But for the impatient just log on to the database and run:

```
create extension postgis;
```

GeoServer makes it as simple to [connect to a remote database](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/postgis.html) as to a local one. All you need to know is the hostname and port, add the username and password for the database and finally the schema you are using.

Comment: Thanks, Ian! I think my problem was mostly my unfamiliarity with the systems involved and over-saturation of information resources. I even had that same page open in one of my dozen tabs. Thanks for your help!

Comment: please upvote and accept the answer if it solves your question

Comment: It's accepted and upvoted. I don't seem to have the rep for the upvote to be visible.